Why can't connect to my websocket endpoint
I am developing a SPA with vuejs + vite
I have a websocket endpoint in my back-end.
And I can connect to that websocket via cli tool websocat.
but when try to connect in javascript, both firefox and chrome show connection error.
the vite developement server was proxying my backend using configs below:
server: {
      // 允许IP访问
      host: "portal-local.itps.xxx.com",
      // 应用端口 (默认:3000)
      port: Number(env.VITE_APP_PORT),
      // 运行是否自动打开浏览器
      open: true,
      https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(
          "/home/ggfan/2-work/git/itps/1A-IaaS-Manifests/kubernetes/1.27/ssl/certs/itps.xxx.com/privkey.pem"
        ),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(
          "/home/ggfan/2-work/git/itps/1A-IaaS-Manifests/kubernetes/1.27/ssl/certs/itps.xxx.com/fullchain.pem"
        ),
      },
      proxy: {
        /**
         * 反向代理解决跨域配置
         * http://localhost:3000/dev-api/users (F12可见请求路径) => http://localhost:8989/users (实际请求后端 API 路径)
         *
         * env.VITE_APP_BASE_API: /dev-api
         * env.VITE_APP_API_URL: http://localhost:8989
         */
        /*
        [env.VITE_APP_BASE_API]: {
          changeOrigin: true,
          target: "http://localhost:8080",
          rewrite: (path) =>
            path.replace(new RegExp("^" + env.VITE_APP_BASE_API), ""),
        },
        */
        ["/oauth2"]: {
          changeOrigin: true,
          target: "https://api.itps.xxx.com",
          // secure: false,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(new RegExp("^" + env.VITE_APP_BASE_API), ""),
          /*
          cookieDomainRewrite: {
            "itps.xxx.com": "localhost",
          },
          */
        },
        ["/pus"]: {
          changeOrigin: true,
          target: "http://localhost:8080",
          // secure: false,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/pus/, ""),
          /*
          cookieDomainRewrite: {
            "itps.xxx.com": "localhost",
          },
          */
          configure: proxyConfig,
        },
        ["/ws"]: {
          changeOrigin: true,
          target: "http://localhost:8080",
          ws: true,
          secure: false,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/ws/, ""),
          configure: proxyConfig,
        },
      },
    }

connecting with websocat:

my typescript code:
  const ws = new WebSocket("wss://portal-local.itps.xxx.com:3000/ws/export/sea/users")
  ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send("{}")
  }
  ws.onmessage = async (event) => {
    console.log(event.data)
    await writable.write(event.data)
  }
  ws.onclose = async (event) => {
    await writable.close()
  }

Chrome error:
SEAExportDialog.vue:104 WebSocket connection to 'wss://portal-local.itps.xxx.com:3000/ws/export/sea/users' failed: 


the certs was obtained from let's encrypt, if that matters.
updates:
using wireshark, I narrowed the problem down to the vite proxy server respond 403:
Frame 22: 844 bytes on wire (6752 bits), 844 bytes captured (6752 bits) on interface lo, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 38478, Dst Port: 3000, Seq: 683, Ack: 4150, Len: 778
Transport Layer Security
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /ws/export/sea/users HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /ws/export/sea/users HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [GET /ws/export/sea/users HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /ws/export/sea/users
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: portal-local.itps.xxx.com:3000\r\n
    Connection: Upgrade\r\n
    Pragma: no-cache\r\n
    Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n
    Upgrade: websocket\r\n
    Origin: https://portal-local.itps.xxx.com:3000\r\n
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd\r\n
    Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9\r\n
    Cookie: _oauth2_proxy=X29hdXRoMl9wcm94eS00ZWU3OTM2NTIwYWYxNjBjNjZlNGQ4ODJkNTA0OGE4Yy5NM0FOUzVJRlBTV2JkN1g2Zlh6RWtB|1713431461|XkFGp00nkvsob926le3vxJ61wpGV44gtE1GeZcl4eEg=\r\n
        Cookie pair: _oauth2_proxy=X29hdXRoMl9wcm94eS00ZWU3OTM2NTIwYWYxNjBjNjZlNGQ4ODJkNTA0OGE4Yy5NM0FOUzVJRlBTV2JkN1g2Zlh6RWtB|1713431461|XkFGp00nkvsob926le3vxJ61wpGV44gtE1GeZcl4eEg=
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: FLMsmXSIxrT0bV1TA8yd/Q==\r\n
    Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: WebSocket\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: https://portal-local.itps.xxx.com:3000/ws/export/sea/users]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 24]

Frame 24: 161 bytes on wire (1288 bits), 161 bytes captured (1288 bits) on interface lo, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 3000, Dst Port: 38478, Seq: 4724, Ack: 1461, Len: 95
Transport Layer Security
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    HTTP/1.1 403 \r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): HTTP/1.1 403 \r\n]
            [HTTP/1.1 403 \r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Response Version: HTTP/1.1
        Status Code: 403
        [Status Code Description: Forbidden]
    content-length: 0\r\n
        [Content length: 0]
    date: Thu, 18 Apr 2024 09:24:37 GMT\r\n
    \r\n
    [HTTP response 1/1]
    [Time since request: 0.011595626 seconds]
    [Request in frame: 22]
    [Request URI: https://portal-local.itps.xxx.com:3000/ws/export/sea/users]



the : after failed: suggests there's more to the error than you've shown

@JaromandaX but there is no more information, I have added picture, you can see it was empty after failed:

Check the request in the network tab of devtools, not the console

it turns out:
it's the backend server returned 403 response.
for me it's spring boot + tomcat, I need to set allowed origins:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private SEAExportWSHandler seaExportWSHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(seaExportWSHandler, "/export/**").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }

}

but it's odd that the chrome browser swallowed the 403 response and give empty error message.
